# LeetCode 1206: Design Skiplist

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem. If you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

> Design a Skiplist without using any built-in libraries.
>
> A Skiplist is a data structure that takes O(log(n)) time to add, erase
> and search. Comparing with treap and red-black tree which has the same
> function and performance, the code length of Skiplist can be
> comparatively short and the idea behind Skiplists are just simple
> linked lists.
>
> For example: we have a Skiplist containing [30,40,50,60,70,90] and we
> want to add 80 and 45 into it. The Skiplist works this way:
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>Artyom Kalinin [CC BY-SA 3.0], via Wikimedia Commons</sup>
>
> You can see there are many layers in the Skiplist. Each layer is a
> sorted linked list. With the help of the top layers, add , erase and
> search can be faster than O(n). It can be proven that the average time
> complexity for each operation is O(log(n)) and space complexity is
> O(n).
>
> To be specific, your design should include these functions:
>
> - `bool search(int target)`: Return whether the target exists in the
>   Skiplist or not.
> - `void add(int num)`: Insert a value into the SkipList.
> - `bool erase(int num)`: Remove a value in the Skiplist. If `num` does not
>   exist in the Skiplist, do nothing and return false. If there exists
>   multiple `num` values, removing any one of them is fine.
>
> See more about Skiplist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list
>
> Note that duplicates may exist in the Skiplist, your code needs to handle this situation.
>
> #### Example:
>
> ```
> Skiplist skiplist = new Skiplist();
>
> skiplist.add(1);
> skiplist.add(2);
> skiplist.add(3);
> skiplist.search(0);   // return false.
> skiplist.add(4);
> skiplist.search(1);   // return true.
> skiplist.erase(0);    // return false, 0 is not in skiplist.
> skiplist.erase(1);    // return true.
> skiplist.search(1);   // return false, 1 has already been erased.
> ```
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - `0 <= num`, `target <= 20000`
> - At most 50000 calls will be made to search, add, and erase.

#### Code

```
// The following block might trivially improve the exec time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();


// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

static const struct Skiplist {
    using SizeType = std::int_fast16_t;
    struct Node {
        SizeType val;
        Node* next{nullptr};
        Node* prev{nullptr};
        Node* down{nullptr};
        Node(SizeType val = 0) {
            this->val = val;
        }
    };

    Node* heads{nullptr};
    SizeType layers = 0;

    Skiplist() {
        std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    }

    const bool search(const SizeType target) {
        if (heads == nullptr) {
            return false;
        }

        auto ptr = heads;

        while (ptr) {
            while (ptr->next && ptr->next->val < target) {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }

            if (ptr->next && ptr->next->val == target) {
                return true;
            }

            ptr = ptr->down;
        }

        return false;
    }

    const void add(const SizeType num) {
        Node* ptr = heads;
        std::vector<Node*> path(layers, nullptr);

        for (SizeType layer = layers - 1; layer >= 0; --layer) {
            while (ptr->next && ptr->next->val < num) {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }

            path[layer] = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->down;
        }

        for (SizeType layer = 0; layer <= std::size(path); ++layer) {
            ptr = new Node(num);

            if (layer == std::size(path)) {
                Node* last = heads;
                heads = new Node();
                heads->down = last;
                heads->next = ptr;
                ptr->prev = heads;
                ++layers;

            } else {
                ptr->next = path[layer]->next;
                ptr->prev = path[layer];
                path[layer]->next = ptr;

                if (ptr->next) {
                    ptr->next->prev = ptr;
                }
            }

            if (layer) {
                ptr->down = path[layer - 1]->next;
            }

            if (std::rand() & 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    const bool erase(const SizeType num) {
        auto ptr = heads;

        for (SizeType layer = layers - 1; layer >= 0; --layer) {
            while (ptr->next && ptr->next->val < num) {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }

            if (ptr->next && ptr->next->val == num) {
                ptr = ptr->next;

                while (ptr) {
                    ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;

                    if (ptr->next) {
                        ptr->next->prev = ptr->prev;
                    }

                    ptr = ptr->down;
                }

                while (heads && heads->next == nullptr) {
                    heads = heads->down;
                    --layers;
                }

                return true;

            } else {
                ptr = ptr->down;

                if (ptr == nullptr) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

#### [LeetCode 1206 - Skip List Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-skiplist/)

#### References

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-skiplist/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-skiplist/discuss/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `SizeType` looks like a misnomer. It feels more like `ValueType`. As a side note, consider making it a `template <typename ValueType> struct SkipList`.
- Testing for `heads == nullptr` in `search` is redundant. The loop will take care of it immediately.
- For DRY I recommend a helper method, akin to `std::lower_bound`, to be used in all interface methods (i.e. `search`, `add`, and `erase`). Yes it requires a very careful design of an iterator.
- `add` may benefit from `Node::Node(val, next, down)` constructor.
- No naked loops, please.

  The `for (SizeType layer = 0; layer <= std::size(path); ++layer)` loop particularly deserves to be a method on its own. Its intention is to promote a freshly inserted node, so `promote_added_node` looks like a good name.